# List post only under the category, exclude child category content

Tags: categories, loop, customization

I wanted to list posts which are directly under a category and not inside the "sub category". In other words, I want to hide all the posts which are from "Sub Category"  in the Parent category view.

My looping code is below.

```
<?php rewind_posts(); if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); global $post; ?>
            <?php get_template_part('includes/loop'); ?>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>    

<!-- loop.php -->

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('home-entry-thumb', array('class' => 'entry-thumb')); ?>
    </a>

    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


    <div class="entry-excerpt">
         <?php the_excerpt(); ?>  
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'themejunkie' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>          
    </div><!-- .entry-excerpt -->

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

to solve this you can create a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates), on this page template

1.get the top level categories only, set parent value to zero

```
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0
  );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
```

2.get posts in all parent categories

```
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $all_posts=get_post('category='.$category->term_id);
    foreach( $myposts as $post ){
      setup_postdata($post)
        echo'<li>';'
        echo'<a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a>';'
        echo'</li>';'
    }
}
```

3.if you not want to create page template, then

in category.php(modify it as your design requirement)

```
 // Get children categories of current cat if they exist
if ( $excludes = get_categories( "child_of=" . $wp_query->get( 'cat' ) ) ) {
    // For each child, add just the ID to an array
    foreach ( $excludes as $key => $value ) {
        $exs[] = $value->term_taxonomy_id;
    }
}

// In Loop
if(have_post()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        //get all category of current post
        $categories = get_the_category();
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            //check if any category is child category of current category 
            if( in_array($category,$exs) )
                continue;
        }
        the_title();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but a page is not what I'm looking for.. I have 150 categories, which have 3-4 sub categories each. So I have around 600 categories, creating pages for each wont be a solution. I believe there is a "category__in" function which can be used in the loop to only list post from the current category and exclude it's sub categories.

Comment: hey naveen, i edit my answer check third step